# Merging duplicate arrays inside Multidimensional array with a key value change in php

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

Here is my multidimensional array :

```
array(
array('object_id' => 10, 'score' => 1),
array('object_id' => 11, 'score' => 1),
array('object_id' => 12, 'score' => 1),
array('object_id' => 11, 'score' => 1),
array('object_id' => 10, 'score' => 1),
array('object_id' => 14, 'score' => 1),
)
```

My expected out put is :

```
array(
    array('object_id' => 10, 'score' => 2),
    array('object_id' => 11, 'score' => 2),
    array('object_id' => 12, 'score' => 1),
    array('object_id' => 14, 'score' => 1),
    )
```

Verbally, what I need is find the unique object_ids inside the multidimensional array and combine their 'score' value. What is the most efficient way to do this in php?

Comment: Just looking at the manual would have been much simpler/faster task than posting this question check http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php#116302

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$output = array();
foreach($array as $e)
{
    if(isset($output[$e['object_id']]))
    {
        $output[$e['object_id']]['score']+=$e['score'];
    }else
    {
        $output[$e['object_id']] = $e;  
    }
}

    print_r(array_values($output));
```

**Here is test**

```
$ cat test.php
<?php

$array = array(
array('object_id' => 10, 'score' => 1),
array('object_id' => 11, 'score' => 1),
array('object_id' => 12, 'score' => 1),
array('object_id' => 11, 'score' => 1),
array('object_id' => 10, 'score' => 1),
array('object_id' => 14, 'score' => 1),
);

$output = array();
foreach($array as $e)
{
    if(isset($output[$e['object_id']]))
    {
        $output[$e['object_id']]['score']+=$e['score'];
    }else
    {
        $output[$e['object_id']] = $e;  
    }
}

// Input
print_r($array);

// Output
print_r(array_values($output));

?>
```

**Output**

```
$ php test.php
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [object_id] => 10
            [score] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [object_id] => 11
            [score] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [object_id] => 12
            [score] => 1
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [object_id] => 11
            [score] => 1
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [object_id] => 10
            [score] => 1
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [object_id] => 14
            [score] => 1
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [object_id] => 10
            [score] => 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [object_id] => 11
            [score] => 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [object_id] => 12
            [score] => 1
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [object_id] => 14
            [score] => 1
        )

)
```